# Visual Studio Code using JavaScript with a TypeScript File as Reference for Intellisense

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am currently using VisualStudioCode to write a nodejs app and I'm using the doc comments to link the parameters of functions to classes so the IntelliSense can kick in, but I encountered some problems when I want to use classes/types of modules.

How I currently handle things:

```
class Foo{
    constructor(){
      this.bar = "value"
    }
}

/**
 * @param {Foo} parameter 
 */
function foobar(parameter){
  parameter.bar.charAt(0); //parameter.bar now with IntelliSense
}
```

In `foobar` I can now see all available attributes/functions I can call on `bar`.

Now, if somewhere in a node-module a TypeScript file:

```
declare module 'coollib' {
  namespace lib {
    type CoolLibType = {
      begin?: string | number | Date;
      liveBuffer?: number;
      requestOptions?: {};
      highWaterMark?: number;
      lang?: string;
    }
  }
  export = lib;
}
```

How can I reference this? I would like to do something like this in my JavaScript file:

```
const CoolLibType = require('coollib')
/**
 * @param {CoolLibType} obj 
 */
function foobar(obj){
  obj.lang.charAt(0); //with cool IntelliSense
}
```

But it obviously doesn't work like this.

Comment: why not write the application entirely in typescript and then use something like TS-Node to build whatever Javascript files afterwards?

Comment: I barley know a thing about TypeScript. I would prefer to stay with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use what's called an *import type*.

```
/**
 * @param {typeof import('coollib')} obj
 */
function foobar(obj) {
  obj.lang.charAt(0); //with cool IntelliSense
}
```

Read more about import types in [TypeScript 2.9 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html).

Comment: Thank you, but like this it only gives me access to function defined in the namespace. However it does work this: @param {import('coollib').CoolLibType}

Comment: There was no way for me to know how your `coollib` is structured. ;-) Iʼm glad you have found a way.